# Mysql Query failure[cant identify]

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently making a student registration form. my query seems to be not working. it didnt save any data to database. i cant find what is the problem.

I'm using `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

```
        $NamaPelajar=$_POST['NamaPenuh'] ;
        $NoKP= $_POST['NoIC'] ;                 
        $Jantina=$_POST['Jantina'] ;
        $Email=$_POST['Email'] ;
        $Katalaluan=$_POST['KataLaluan'] ;
        $AlamatPelajar1=$_POST['alamat'] ;
        $PoskodPelajar=$_POST['Poskod'] ;
        $BandarPelajar=$_POST['bandar'] ;
        $NegeriPelajar=$_POST['Negeri'] ;
        $NoTelPelajar=$_POST['NoTelPelajar'] ;
        $NamaInstitusi=$_POST['NamaUni'] ;
        $AlamatInstitusi1=$_POST['alamatp'] ;
        $PoskodInstitusi=$_POST['Poskodp'] ;
        $BandarInstitusi=$_POST['bandarp'] ;
        $NegeriInstitusi=$_POST['Negerip'] ;
        $Kelayakan=$_POST['Kelayakan'] ;
        $Jurusan=$_POST['kos'] ;
        $Tempoh=$_POST['Tempoh'] ;
        $Mula=$_POST['mula'] ;
        $Tamat=$_POST['akhir'] ;
        $NoTelPenyelia=$_POST['NoPenyelia'] ;

        $AlamatPelajar = ($AlamatPelajar1).' '.($PoskodPelajar)
                            .' '.($BandarPelajar).' '.($NegeriPelajar);

        $AlamatInstitusi = ($AlamatInstitusi1).' '.($PoskodInstitusi)
                            .' '.($BandarInstitusi).' '.($NegeriInstitusi);
```

this is the query

Already triple check in database, try using new database, check post variable.

```
     $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pelajar`
                    (NamaPelajar,NoKpPelajar,JantinaPelajar,EmailPelajar,
                    KataLaluanPelajar,AlamatPelajar,NoTelPelajar,NamaInstitusi,AlamatInstitusi,
                    KelayakanPelajar,JurusanPelajar,TempohLatihan,TarikhMula,TarikhTamat,NoTelPenyelia)
                    VALUES ('$NamaPelajar','$NoKP','$Jantina','$Email','$Katalaluan','$AlamatPelajar',
                    '$NoTelPelajar','$NamaInstitusi','$AlamatInstitusi','$Kelayakan','$Jurusan','$Tempoh',
                    '$Mula','$Tamat','$NoTelPenyelia')");
                    if($query)
                        {
                        $url = 'Succes.php';
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        $url = 'Fail.php';
                        }

                    header('Location: ' . $url);
                    exit();
```

everytime i run it, always head to `Fail.php`

Comment: First of all, you should really migrate to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) ... Did you try to see if it returns any errors? What did you do to debug it?

Comment: no error when i run it, it just head to `fail.php` after submit.

Comment: Did you call mysql_error() ??

Comment: 15 columns and 14 values?

Comment: @Mariano how to call `mysql_error()`??

Comment: @jimmypage  already add another column

Comment: @Mariano lolx, thx for the tips, works great now :D

Comment: if(!$query) { echo mysql_error(); }; And yes, migrate to mysqli !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should really use PreparedStatements or at least escape the data otherwise your database is open for SQL-injection.

Your query is within a string, so the new lines and whitespaces are probably counted towards the column-names, you have to remove them.

You can use `echo mysql_error();` to print the last error.

Anyway better have a look at **PDO** or **mysqli** since the use of mysql is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Build query in php and return it to browser.

```
    $insertSQL =  "INSERT INTO `pelajar` (NamaPelajar,NoKpPelajar,JantinaPelajar,EmailPelajar, KataLaluanPelajar,AlamatPelajar,NoTelPelajar,NamaInstitusi,AlamatInstitusi, KelayakanPelajar,JurusanPelajar,TempohLatihan,TarikhMula,TarikhTamat,NoTelPenyelia) VALUES ('$NamaPelajar','$NoKP','$Jantina','$Email','$Katalaluan','$AlamatPelajar', '$NoTelPelajar','$NamaInstitusi','$AlamatInstitusi','$Kelayakan','$Jurusan','$Tempoh', '$Mula','$Tamat','$NoTelPenyelia')";
    echo $insertSQL;
```

Run generated query in sql client console, gui or phpMyAdmin to find cause